# python adding PIL image into a pdf file

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, qr-code

How can I add a PIL image created by qrcode library into a PDF file. Below is the code and error message that I get.

```
> def WriteQRCodeToPDF:
>     p = canvas.Canvas("document-output.pdf")
>     pagesize=letter
>     width, height = letter
>     image = ImageReader(GenerateQRCode("data"));
>     p.drawImage(image, inch, height - 2 * inch, 100,100);
>     p.showPage()
>     p.save()
> 
> def GenerateQRCode(qrdata):
>     qr = qrcode.QRCode(
>         version=1,
>         error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
>         box_size=10,
>         border=4,
>     )
>     qr.add_data(qrdata)
>     qr.make(fit=True)
>     img = qr.make_image()
>     return img
```

error message is as below. It seems like ImageReader do not accept PIL image as parameter.What could I use instead of it

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 657, in open_for_read
>     return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 601, in open_for_read_by_name
>     return open(name,mode) TypeError: invalid file: <qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0xb6a9ccac>
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 660, in open_for_read
>     return getBytesIO(datareader(name) if name.startswith('data:') else urlopen(name).read())   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 35,
> in __getattr__
>     return getattr(self._img, name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 610, in
> __getattr__
>     raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: startswith
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./qrcodegenerator.py", line
> 44, in <module>
>     main()   File "./qrcodegenerator.py", line 41, in main
>     WriteQRCodeToPDF(dataList)   File "./qrcodegenerator.py", line 21, in WriteQRCodeToPDF
>     image = ImageReader(GenerateQRCode("data1"));   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 800, in __init__
>     annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity()))   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 1380, in annotateException
>     rl_reraise(t,v,b)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 137, in rl_reraise
>     raise v   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 764, in __init__
>     self.fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line
> 662, in open_for_read
>     raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name) OSError: Cannot open resource "<qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0xb6a9ccac>"
> fileName=<qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0xb6a9ccac>
> identity=[ImageReader@0xb6a9cc2c]
```

Comment: where is the error message ?

Comment: I have just added it

Answer (score 2):

I have used QRCode (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode).

This is the snippet of code that works for me:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="backup_key.pdf"'
p = canvas.Canvas(response)
img = qrcode.make(data)
image = ImageReader(img._img)
p.drawImage(image, 10, 10)
```